# How do you unlock the craftable Inazuma weapons?

Tags: genshin-impact

I can't seem to find their crafting recipes anywhere. I tried going to the forge at Inazuma City, but no one is selling or offering it. I figured it might have something to do with the City Reputation system, but it's not available in the list of rewards. I checked the Divine Sakura tree and that's not listed as a reward either, granted I can't see that far up the list.

So now I'm curious -- where do I get the blueprints for these weapons? As far as I remember the blueprints for craftable Liyue and Mondstadt weapons were there from the start, but it seems my Forge does not have those blueprints at all which I assume you have to unlock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Amenoma Kageuchi (Inazuma sword)

1. Complete the *Sacred Sakura Cleansing Ritual* quest until you obtain the **Memento Lens** item
2. Complete the *Strange Story in Konda* quest
3. Rescue the stranger atop of Jinren Island
4. Collect 4 Stone Tablets scattered across Inazuma
5. Complete the *Farmer's Treasure* quest to obtain the blueprint for the sword.

---

#### Katsuragikiri Nagamasa (Inazuma claymore)

1. Complete the *Tatara Tales* questline until the rift barriers have been destroyed.
2. Find the 3 **Key To Some Place** in Tatarasuna
3. Unlock the *Open Arsenal Gate* at the bottom of Tatarasuna.

[image]

4. Defeat the Ruin Automatons, open the chest, and claim the blueprint.

---

#### Hakushin Ring (Inazuma catalyst)

1. Complete the entire *Sacred Sakura Cleansing Ritual* questline to obtain the **Mask of Memories** item. Using this item unlocks the recipe for the catalyst.

---

#### Kitain Cross Spear (Inazuma polearm)

1. Complete the entire *Orobashi's Legacy* questline to receive the blueprint.

---

#### Hamayumi (Inazuma bow)

1. Collect 3 conches every day and turn them into Takashi in his shell hut in north Kannazuka.
2. Open 1 of the 3 chests (does not matter).
3. On the 7th day of turning in 3 conches you will receive the blueprint for the Hamayumi bow.